# Cannot start mysql server. Error

Tags: mysql, mysqld

I'm on Ubuntu 20.4 and did some apt update/upgrade. Not sure what package was changed, but I'm unable to start my mysql server due to these error:

===
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2022-06-09T04:05:14.093531Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2022-06-09T04:05:14.093553Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) starting as process 1974
2022-06-09T04:05:14.097652Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-06-09T04:05:14.895737Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-06-09T04:05:15.184723Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2022-06-09T04:05:15.184755Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2022-06-09T04:05:15.208172Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2022-06-09T04:05:15.208213Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
04:05:15 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x7f854c000b60
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7f85667fbc10 thread_stack 0x78000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x41) [0x5632646f8ad1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(print_fatal_signal(int)+0x2fb) [0x5632635997db]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0xa5) [0x563263599895]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x14420) [0x7f85e376e420]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(page_cur_search_with_match_bytes(buf_block_t const*, dict_index_t const*, dtuple_t const*, page_cur_mode_t, unsigned long*, unsigned long*, unsigned long*, unsigned long*, page_cur_t*)+0x1c2) [0x56326484f482]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(btr_cur_search_to_nth_level(dict_index_t*, unsigned long, dtuple_t const*, page_cur_mode_t, unsigned long, btr_cur_t*, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long, mtr_t*)+0x1f62) [0x5632649c0c82]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(row_search_on_row_ref(btr_pcur_t*, unsigned long, dict_table_t*, dtuple_t const*, mtr_t*)+0xd3) [0x5632648c40b3]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x2452899) [0x5632648ba899]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x24532d1) [0x5632648bb2d1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(row_purge_step(que_thr_t*)+0x92a) [0x5632648bf33a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(que_run_threads(que_thr_t*)+0xe28) [0x563264870348]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(srv_worker_thread()+0x580) [0x5632648fc400]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<Detached_thread, void (*)()> > >::_M_run()+0xbc) [0x56326480208c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xd6de4) [0x7f85e2cc5de4]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8609) [0x7f85e3762609]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x43) [0x7f85e29b2133]

## Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 0
Status: NOT_KILLED

Stuck and my web sites are down. Any help regarding the bug or reverting all the update the last hours appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One of the table of the database was corrupt. Had to:

1. Set innodb recovery to 2 in my.cnf
2. Log into the server and drop the database
3. Remove the innodb recovey from the my.cnf
4. Restart the mysql server
5. Reload the DB from backup.

Comment: Congratulatons.  Now, enjoy the weekend.